# What should we name our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Our [primary chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3819) is named "Islam" (described as "General discussion for islam.stackexchange.com").  While accurate, I feel that this is decidedly *boring*.

So, given that being boring is bad and being interesting is good, what should we name it instead?

Comment: I think the name and its relevance to Islam should be clear from the name alone both for Muslims and non-Muslims.

Comment: I wish it was an English name, not an Arabic one. Now it sounds nothing to those who don't know Arabic.

Answer (score 4):

I would somehow like to work Stack Exchange into the chat name itself.  Extending from [Al Ummat's answer](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/726/22), something like **Ijtima al-StackExchange** (the definite 'al-' more because it amuses me than because it's grammatically necessary).

From another word based on the root *j-m-'* (assembly/group/etc), I also had **Jaami'at al-Stackexchange** (University of (the) Stack Exchange) rattling around as an idea.

Comment: I like the second idea better.  Also, if we do choose that, I think it should be considered adding "Al-Islamy" so it becomes "Jaami'at (al)StackExchange Al-Islamy"

Comment: @AlUmmatمجاهد that and even goldpsueds name   sounds too funny and tacky

Answer (score 2):

We can either have it's name in Arabic (transliterated), or in English.

If people are more inclined to an Arabic name, then the name of the chatroom can be:

Ijtima' Al Mujtama' (اجتماع المجتمع)

if in English, perhaps the name can be:

The Gathering

Comment: Ijtima is enough

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply "The Ummah?"

As I understand the concept, the body of believers is central to ascertain the will of Allah.  The chat room would be populated mostly by said Ummah.

Comment: I would worry that this would make the chat room seem more "No non-Muslims allowed" than we intend.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend [Halaqa - Gathering to learn Islam](http://ya-mujeeb.com/index.php/sharai-masaeel/beliefs-and-practices/does-the-term-halaka-halqa-halaqa-have-any-background)

---

Since this site is more exposed to the non Muslims , It should be something that anyone should be able to understand and catchy too, some suggestions:

- I Submit
- Islam and me
- Halaka - The gathering
- Come to Light
- Come to Islam
- The Muslim Hangout for Non Muslims

Comment: What does "Halaka" mean?

Comment: Halaka means a gathering by a scholar for learning Islam, I know it is similar to the Jewish Halacha, we call the Halacha as Sharia @DoubleAA